# flutter deploy to ios device fixing issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

flutter deployed to test flight after facing issues

Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

I created an application using flutter. In android the app is working well. In ios there is a problem.

it is an invoice-generating app. In android the textformfield is displayed. In ios debugging it is displaying when i released in testflight it is not displaying.

({ios}) the field is messing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me due to the incorrect use of Expanded widget or when ! was used on a null variable.

In case of the Expanded widget, there will be an error in the console Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. If this is the problem then you should check where you are using the Expanded widget.

Expanded widget must be used within a Column, Row, or Flex.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by Rendering issues. On `--release` mode, when a RenderFlex issue occurs it just hides the widget. However on `--debug` mode you'll see the yellow warning stripes

Try to debug your application in different screen sizes first, so you can ensure that your layout is properly responsive.